# Using local database in VSTO with SQLite

Tags: c#, vsto, sqlite-net

As my VSTO is growing up in the usage it comes harder to make it work without having a database.
To make it work I need to have a local database used by the app like the sqlite-net-pcl does in any Xamarin app.

My VSTO was fully functional and i tried to add the NuGet package and using it the same way I used to in my previous Xamarin. Unfortunately it doesn't work and keep refusing to connect throwing the missing package 'e_sqlite3'. I've been looking for a solution in the NuGet package manager re-installing and trying various version but no solution.

I am now looking for either a solution of this problem or an alternative that could be the most look-a-like to keep going on my project without having to re-learn too many stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` (newer, maintained by Microsoft) or `System.Data.SQLite` (older, maintained by the SQLite developers)?

I suspect the former; this looks like [a long-standing bug with `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` on .NET Framework](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19396).

I suggest switching to `System.Data.SQLite`, it's worked much better with .NET Framework for me. If you use ClickOnce to deploy your VSTO add-in, note that [you will need to do a bit of folder setup for ClickOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038929/how-to-publish-a-winforms-app-with-sqlite-using-clickonce).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I actually started over the project from scratch and found alternatives for my own needs. 
If i have the time in the near future to try your solution i'll do and i'll keep an eye on this post.

Comment: @XimazeC can you please mention the alternatives you've found... Or add a new answer with your solutions and mark it as an answer so that people with the same problems might benefit from it

Comment: Sorry but I actually can't say it is a solution because i rethinked the whole app to make it work. For my needs the solution fit but i'm sure it will not for any other project so think about an API or a separate database and build around for your needs