# Exception after ClickOnce deployment on StartUp

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

After multiple hours, google searches and trying to go back to previous code I can't get this weird Exception out of the way. So I'm open for any suggestion.

I did an update to an existing ClickOnce-Deployment Project of mine and in Debug everything works totally fine. After finishing the update I wanted to test the application in my own network as it is a multi-user app. Turns out I must've destroyed something along the way and because I didn't back-up the old code I can't do a rollback.

I added an Exception-catching code in the App.xaml.cs to write into a log, so if the users get an exception I can check the logs and act accordingly. This is where following log comes from:

> Zeilennummer "8" und Zeilenposition "9" von "Durch den Aufruf des Konstruktors für Typ "MietPlaner2020.MainWindow", der den angegebenen Bindungseinschränkungen entspricht, wurde eine Ausnahme ausgelöst.".
> bei System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
> bei System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
> bei System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
> bei System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
> bei System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
> bei System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
> bei System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
> bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
> bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

On my google searches I found this translation into english:

> The invocation of the constructor on type 'TestWPF.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

The code of the MainWindow-Constructor looks like that

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        CheckInstallation();

        //Min Window Size
        MinHeight = 720;
        MinWidth = 1280;

        CurrentlyShownDates = new List<DateTime>();
        CurrentDate = DateTime.Today;
        DayPickedDirectly = false;

        AddScrollBarColumn();

        LoadData();
    }
```

Row-Number "8" and Row-Position "9" are in any way I count the lines not logical. It's never a =-sign, only a random letter in the code, so I honestly don't know what to do.

As it only happens when the app is installed I can't go through the code with the debugger, as I can't reproduce the Exception before deployment.

Thanks in advance, hoping I can get this fixed.

As Stephan asked, here is the MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MietPlaner2020.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MietPlaner2020"
    xmlns:modals="clr-namespace:MietPlaner2020.Modals"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MietPlaner2020.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="1200"
    Title="Miet Planer" Loaded="LoadEntries" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<DockPanel>
    <!-- TODO: Add as soon as local station logic is needed -->
    <!--<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="MainStatusBar">
        <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="StatusBarGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="230" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="230" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="Stations HERE" />
        </StatusBarItem>
        <Separator Grid.Column="1" />
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock x:Name="StationInformation" Text="Station Name + ID HERE" />
        </StatusBarItem>
        <Separator Grid.Column="3" />
        <StatusBarItem x:Name="DataUpdateStatusItem" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
            <TextBlock x:Name="DataUpdateStatusText" Text="Daten aktuell" />
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <DockPanel x:Name="CalendarPanel">
                <Grid x:Name="ButtonGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="125" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Button"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Button"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Button"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="AddEntryButton" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="125" Margin="10,0" Tag="Entry_Add" Content="_Termin hinzufügen" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}" Click="OpenPopup"/>
                        <Button x:Name="AvailabilityCheckButton" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0" Tag="AvailabilityCheck" Content="_Verfügbarkeit" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}" Click="OpenPopup"/>
                        <Button x:Name="ContractButton" Grid.Column="3" Margin="10,0" Tag="Contract" Content="Vertrag erstellen" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}" Click="OpenPopup"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Button x:Name="DecreaseWeekButton" MinWidth="20" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="DecreaseWeek" Style="{DynamicResource PreviousButtonStyle}" Height="{Binding ElementName=PickWeek, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=DecreaseWeekButton, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="PickWeek" Tag="WeekPicker" MinWidth="400" MinHeight="47" MaxHeight="47" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="OpenPopup" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}">
                            <Grid>
                                <AccessText Text="_Kalender" Opacity="0"/>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="PickWeek_Month" Text="MONTH" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="PickWeek_Week" Text="WEEK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="IncreaseWeekButton" MinWidth="20" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="IncreaseWeek" Style="{DynamicResource NextButtonStyle}" Height="{Binding ElementName=PickWeek, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=IncreaseWeekButton, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="125" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Button"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Button"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Button"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="ImportantEntriesButton" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0" Tag="ImportantEntries" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}" Click="OpenPopup">
                            <Viewbox Width="32" Height="32" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
                                <Rectangle Width="32" Height="32">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <DrawingBrush>
                                            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                                <DrawingGroup>
                                                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M8,16C3.589,16 0,12.411 0,8 0,3.589 3.589,0 8,0 12.411,0 16,3.589 16,8 16,12.411 12.411,16 8,16" />
                                                        <GeometryDrawing x:Name="ImportantEntriesMarkBackgroundColor" Brush="#80424242" Geometry="F1M9,10L7,10 7,3 9,3z M9,13L7,13 7,11 9,11z M8,1C4.134,1 1,4.134 1,8 1,11.865 4.134,15 8,15 11.865,15 15,11.865 15,8 15,4.134 11.865,1 8,1" />
                                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M9,11L7,11 7,13 9,13z M9,10L7,10 7,3 9,3z" />
                                                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                </DrawingGroup>
                                            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                        </DrawingBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="SettingsButton" Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="125" Margin="10,0" Tag="Settings" Click="OpenPopup" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Grid>
                                    <AccessText Text="_Einstellungen" Opacity="0"/>
                                    <Viewbox Width="32" Height="32" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
                                        <Rectangle Width="32" Height="32">
                                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                <DrawingBrush>
                                                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                                        <DrawingGroup>
                                                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M5.9859,-0.000199999999999534L5.6129,2.2378 3.7669,0.918800000000001 0.9189,3.7668 2.2369,5.6128 -9.99999999997669E-05,5.9858 -9.99999999997669E-05,10.0118 2.2369,10.3868 0.9189,12.2338 3.7669,15.0798 5.6119,13.7628 5.9859,15.9998 10.0129,15.9998 10.3869,13.7618 12.2339,15.0798 15.0799,12.2338 13.7619,10.3868 15.9999,10.0148 15.9999,5.9868 13.7619,5.6128 15.0799,3.7668 12.2339,0.919800000000001 10.3869,2.2378 10.0139,-0.000199999999999534z" />
                                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF424242" Geometry="F1M10.2123,8C10.2123,9.222 9.2223,10.212 8.0003,10.212 6.7783,10.212 5.7873,9.222 5.7873,8 5.7873,6.778 6.7783,5.788 8.0003,5.788 9.2223,5.788 10.2123,6.778 10.2123,8z M9.9643,3.257C9.8183,3.197,9.6683,3.17,9.5203,3.124L9.1663,1 6.8333,1 6.4803,3.121C6.1853,3.213,5.8993,3.332,5.6253,3.475L3.8753,2.225 2.2253,3.875 3.4773,5.627C3.4053,5.764 3.3183,5.89 3.2573,6.036 3.1973,6.182 3.1703,6.331 3.1243,6.479L1.0003,6.833 1.0003,9.166 3.1213,9.52C3.2133,9.815,3.3313,10.101,3.4753,10.375L2.2253,12.125 3.8753,13.775 5.6273,12.523C5.7643,12.595 5.8893,12.682 6.0353,12.742 6.1813,12.803 6.3313,12.83 6.4793,12.876L6.8333,15 9.1663,15 9.5203,12.879C9.8153,12.787,10.1013,12.668,10.3743,12.525L12.1243,13.775 13.7743,12.125 12.5233,10.373C12.5953,10.236 12.6823,10.11 12.7423,9.964 12.8033,9.818 12.8303,9.669 12.8763,9.521L15.0003,9.167 15.0003,6.834 12.8783,6.48C12.7863,6.185,12.6683,5.899,12.5243,5.625L13.7743,3.875 12.1253,2.225 10.3723,3.477C10.2353,3.405,10.1103,3.318,9.9643,3.257z" />
                                                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                        </DrawingGroup>
                                                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                                </DrawingBrush>
                                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                                        </Rectangle>
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </Grid>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="PrintButton" Grid.Column="3" Margin="10,0" Click="PrintButton_Click" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Grid>
                                    <AccessText Text="_Drucken" Opacity="0"/>
                                    <Viewbox Width="32" Height="32" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
                                        <Rectangle Width="32" Height="32">
                                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                <DrawingBrush>
                                                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                                        <DrawingGroup>
                                                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M15.2686,6.73C14.7906,6.252,14.1786,6,13.4996,6L12.9996,6 12.9996,0 2.9996,0 2.9996,6 2.4996,6C1.8206,6 1.2076,6.252 0.730599999999999,6.73 0.252599999999999,7.208 -0.000400000000000844,7.82 -0.000400000000000844,8.5L-0.000400000000000844,14 2.9996,14 2.9996,16 12.9996,16 12.9996,14 15.9996,14 15.9996,8.5C15.9996,7.822,15.7476,7.21,15.2686,6.73" />
                                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M5,14L11,14 11,12 5,12z M11,2L5,2 5,7 11,7z M14,8.5L14,12 12,12 12,11 4,11 4,12 2,12 2,8.5C2,8.354 2.047,8.234 2.141,8.141 2.234,8.047 2.354,8 2.5,8L13.5,8C13.646,8 13.766,8.047 13.859,8.141 13.953,8.234 14,8.354 14,8.5" />
                                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF424242" Geometry="F1M11,12L5,12 5,14 11,14z M5,7L11,7 11,2 5,2z M3,10L4,10 4,9 3,9z M14,8.5C14,8.354 13.953,8.234 13.859,8.141 13.766,8.047 13.646,8 13.5,8L2.5,8C2.354,8 2.234,8.047 2.141,8.141 2.047,8.234 2,8.354 2,8.5L2,12 4,12 4,11 12,11 12,12 14,12z M15,13L12,13 12,15 4,15 4,13 1,13 1,8.5C1,8.083 1.146,7.729 1.437,7.437 1.729,7.146 2.083,7 2.5,7L4,7 4,1 12,1 12,7 13.5,7C13.916,7 14.271,7.146 14.563,7.437 14.854,7.729 15,8.083 15,8.5z" />
                                                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                        </DrawingGroup>
                                                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                                </DrawingBrush>
                                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                                        </Rectangle>
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </Grid>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid x:Name="CalendarGrid">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1,2,0,2" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Grid x:Name="BackgroundGrid">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="0">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Label Content="Montag" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Label>
                                    <Label x:Name="Day1" Content="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="1">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Label Content="Dienstag" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Label>
                                    <Label x:Name="Day2" Content="2" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="2">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Label Content="Mittwoch" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Label>
                                    <Label x:Name="Day3" Content="3" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="3">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Label Content="Donnerstag" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Label>
                                    <Label x:Name="Day4" Content="4" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="4">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Label Content="Freitag" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Label>
                                    <Label x:Name="Day5" Content="5" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="5">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Label Content="Samstag" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Label>
                                    <Label x:Name="Day6" Content="6" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="6">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Label Content="Sonntag" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Label>
                                    <Label x:Name="Day7" Content="7" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="CategoriesScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <Grid x:Name="EntriesGrid">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Could you please add the corresponding XAML as well?

Comment: Thanks for the XAML. I don't see anything obviously "strange"... I think we need more details. Try to log the InnerException(s) (just use `ex.ToString()`) so we get more information about the real problem here...

Comment: Thanks for that, I used ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, with ex.ToString() I got this line now: `Zeilennummer "8" und Zeilenposition "9" von "Durch den Aufruf des Konstruktors für Typ "MietPlaner2020.MainWindow", der den angegebenen Bindungseinschränkungen entspricht, wurde eine Ausnahme ausgelöst.". ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Die DLL "SQLite.Interop.dll": Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E) kann nicht geladen werden.`
So I know where the problem is based, now I just need to get my Nuget Packages to show again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution here: [How to Publish a Winforms App with SQLite using ClickOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038929/how-to-publish-a-winforms-app-with-sqlite-using-clickonce)

Short Explanation: Getting SQLite via Nuget won't add the SQLite.Interop.dll into the ClickOnce Deployment. You need to add those by hand. On how you can do that, follow the link.